# What is default Content-type of the Apps Script's doPost(e) Funtion? application/json OR form-encoded?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, http-post, content-type

When a program sends the app an HTTP POST request, to Apps Script's doPost(e), which Content-Type is expected by default, "application/json" or "xxx-www-form-encoded"?

I am using pythons requests library. we can choose the Content-Type of the payload.

Comment: I don't think it matters. I expect all content type to be supported.

Comment: @discoMonkey Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I understood that my answer was not useful for your situation. So I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users.  This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again.

Answer (score 0):

As a sample script of doPost of Web Apps, the following sample Google Apps Script is used.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var myJSON = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  MailApp.sendEmail("xxx@gmail.com", "this is a test subject", myJSON.body);
}
```

**Content Type: application/json**

```
import requests
url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec'
payload = {'hello': 'world', 'body': 'this is the body of message..'}
response = requests.post(url, json=payload) # sending json-encoded data
```

**Response:**

`inbox-> this is the body of message..`

**Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

```
import requests
url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec'
payload = {'hello': 'world', 'body': 'this is the body of message..'}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload) # sending form-encoded data
print(response.text)
```

**Response:**

```
(SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0)
```

Can we conclude that the expected Content-Type for the doPost(e) Funtion is the application/json?